# Restoring mysql dump on a master

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a master which is replicated by five slaves. I need to restore a database on the master and plan to do so with mysql db_name < db_name.dump. My question is do I need to stop mysql on the master before I do so for the slaves to automatically pick up the changes? If so what commands must I execute before doing mysql db_name < db_name.dump ?

Comment: Or would it just be simpler to do the same mysql db_name < db_name.dump  on each slave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens:

1. The master runs all the changes in the dump file (mostly CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements).
2. The master logs all those changes in its binary log.
3. Each replica downloads the binary log from the master.
4. Each replica replays the same changes.

You don't need to stop anything. All the replicas will replicate the changes, as long as you have configured replication correctly.

Comment: I could not test your answer because I got impatient and wrote a perl script that updated the corrupted table in the master record by record. However, I will mark it as correct in good faith. Thank you for responding.